# Issues with backslash, quotations in changing the target path of desktop shortcut

Tags: string, vbscript, shortcut-file

I would like to substitute the target of a desktop shortcut, and I did it. But the problem is, I could not configure the new path as the way I like it to be.
The following is my code:

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Java basics.lnk")

lnk.targetpath = "C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe ""\\kk-05\apps\network\logon\kbs_logon_file.vbs"""
lnk.arguments = ""
lnk.save
```

The above code can be compiled and run successfully, but the updated target is :

> "C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe \kk-05\apps\network\logon\kbs_logon_file.vbs"

what I want is:

> C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe "\\kk-05\apps\network\logon\kbs_logon_file.vbs"

The double quotes do not work properly, why can't just use double backslash like this //?
It seems that no matter how many / I typed, it only shows one after execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

`lnk.targetpath = "C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe " 
lnk.arguments =  """\\kk-05\apps\network\logon\kbs_logon_file.vbs"""`

Comment: Hi @Travis G, thanks for the prompt reply, I followed your way, but still doesn't work, the error is :"Expected literal constant" Code: 800A0415. Any suggestions on this? Thanks

Comment: my bad...i have fixed it now.